# Options for chat API in V2?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, chat

We have an education National Program called "Dale Aceptar"[1], where using a ChatBot creator we teach high school kids basic programing concepts like variables and regular expressions. 
One of the key part of it is the kids connecting their chatbot to Facebook chat and let it chat with their friends get feedback.

Also with this software the National university of Cordoba won the "Google Roots in Science and Engineering (RISE) Awards"

I'm part of the team who build the software @ Lvklabs.com [2]. Can you please point me some options to have access to the FB chat api after migration to V2 is complete?

Thanks

PDA

[1]http://www.daleaceptar.gob.ar/
[2]http://www.lvklabs.com/#/theproducts

Comment: No there are no options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

> The service and API this document covers has been deprecated with the release of Platform API v2.0. Once version 1.0 is deprecated, chat.facebook.com will no longer be available.

There are no plans to replace the Chat API. But even with the Chat API, i would see 2 problems:

- User profiles can only be created for real users. A chat bot is not a real user.
- The messages must bei user generated, bot messages would not be allowed.

Not sure if that would be good enough for you, but you could also create a Facebook Page for the bot and use the conversations endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/conversations

You can´t initiate a conversation, but you can reply: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/conversation/messages